# Why do you have to select 'trust server certificate' as well as 'encrypt connection' on one sql server conn and only 'encrypt connection' on another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, certificate

I've applied certificates and enforced encryption on two SQL 2016 SP2 servers. Using the same login credentials I can create an encrypted connection to one of the servers by selecting 'encrypt connection' in the connections options. With the second server unless I also select 'trust server certificate' I get a connection error:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
provider: SSL Provider, The target principal name is incorrect
Error Code  -2146893022
The target principal name is incorrect
If I select 'trust server certificate' as well as 'encrypt connection' in the connection options it connects fine and I can see encrypted connections in dm_exec_connections so the 'incorrect principal name' error seems to be false clue.
Why would you have to select 'trust server certificate' as well as 'encrypt connection' in the connection options on one server and only 'encrypt connection' on another?

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: one of the server's public key certificates is in your Trusted Roots store (or your machine's Trusted Roots store) and the other is not; or the self-signed certificates have been created differently and the one that's not working doesn't include the server name/IP address you're using in your connection string in its list of DnsName attributes.

Comment: thanks, yes the issue does seem to be around DNS settings. When I use the fully qualified domain name as the server name it works without the 'trust server certificate' option. So when the cert was created maybe they didn't add all the DNS options in.

Comment: If you have administrative access to the SQL Server you'll be able to find its certificate in Manage Computer Certificates > Personal > Certificates and check which names are in its DnsName list attribute. Either that or connect with `openssl s_client` and dump the public key certificate to a file.